# Relatively Sized Rectangles in Kivy Widget Canvas

Tags: python, kivy

I created the following Widget, which does correctly draw a checkerboard pattern. However, the edge_len variable is not (apparently) obeying the asserted definitions.

```
        with self.canvas:
        # Define the lengths of the edges of the squares. TODO: Check for relative growth.
        edge_len = min(self.height, self.width) // 8
        for column in range(0, 8):
            for row in range(0, 8):
                if ((row + column) % 2) == 0:
                    graphics.Color(0, 0, 1)
                    self.dark_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
                else:
                    graphics.Color(1, 1, 1)
                    self.light_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
```

I'm currently just running the App to return a `Boxlayout()` with this Widget as its only element. When `edge_len = min(self.height, self.width) // 8` is there, it makes the board quite small. When `edge_len = min(self.height, self.width)` is used, instead, the eighth checkerboard tile does end at the window's width, but extends much higher than that.

I'm trying to work out how to keep the drawn result relatively sized to its layout container/child, but still perfectly square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy provided documentation [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/drawing.html).

And here's the relevant change in code:

```
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Chessboard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(pos=self.drawBoardandPieces)
        self.bind(size=self.drawBoardandPieces)
        self.drawBoardandPieces()

    def drawBoardandPieces(self, *args):
        with self.canvas:
            # Reset everything in case of redraws.
            self.canvas.clear()
            # Define the lengths of the edges of the squares. TODO: Check for relative growth.
            edge_len = min(self.height, self.width) // 8
            Config.set("graphics", "resizable", True)
            for column in range(0, 8):
                for row in range(0, 8):
                    if ((row + column) % 2) == 0:
                        graphics.Color(0, 0, 1)
                        self.dark_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
                    else:
                        graphics.Color(1, 1, 1)
                        self.light_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
```